# Best way to move code from angular controller to factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
   $http({
    'url': $scope.clientResult.resource_server_base_uri  + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions',
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers':{'Authorization': 'bearer ' + $scope.clientResult.access_token,'content-Type': 'application/json'},
    'data': $scope.startSessionPayload
}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    console.log('data', $scope.data)
}).error(function(status) {
    $scope.status = status;
});
```

I'm a bit new to angular and development in general. What would be the best way for me to move this code out of my controller in angular and into a factory. I feel this would be more modular / maintainable, right? I'm a bit confused, as the code references the current controllers $scope.

Comment: Start by removing `$scope.` and make them vars. Or make them parameters passed in through your service's functions. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked a good question. The AngularJS team in their (lack of) infinite wisdom created a horrible method called `.success`. Don't use that buggy thing; use `.then` instead.

`$http` returns a promise, use that.

In your factory:

```
var httpPromise = $http(url);
return httpPromise;
```

In your controller, invoke the promise's `.then` method.

```
httpPromiseFromFactory.then(function (response) {
       vm.data = response.data;
   }) .catch( function(error) {
       throw error;
   });
```

For more information on `$http` and the deprecation of the `.success` method, see the latest [AngularJS $http API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

For more information on AngularJS promises, see the [AngularJS $q Service API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pattern I've been using lately:

1. **AjaxService**: Generic top-level AJAX service that only handles the `$http` call.
2. **DataAccessService**: Mid-tier service that offers `GET` and `POST` request methods. This service injects `AjaxService`.
3. **MyCustomService**: The business layer service that would be getting orders, customers, whatever. This service injects `DataAccessService`.

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/o1jUauTLQNLKx3dk6vrZ

**AjaxService**

```
app.service('AjaxService', function($http) {
  return {
    request: function(options) {
      return $http(options);
    }
  }
});
```

**DataAccessService**

```
app.service('DataAccessService', ['AjaxService', function(AjaxService) {

  var _request = function(method, url, data) {
    var options = {
      method: method,
      url: url,
      data: data
    }
    return AjaxService.request(options);
  };

  return {
    get: function(url) {
      return _request('GET', url);
    },
    post: function(url, data) {
      return _request('POST', url, data);
    }
  }

}]);
```

**MyCustomService**

```
app.service('MyCustomService', function(DataAccessService) {
  return  {
    getMyData: function() {
      return DataAccessService.get('/mydata');
    },
    getMyDataPage: function(pageNumber) {
      return DataAccessService.get('/mydata/page/' + pageNumber);
    },
    saveMyData: function(myData) {
      return DataAccessService.post('/mydata', myData);
    }
  }
})
```